# can't make the rails console run on cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin

Thanks in advance.

I'm running Rails under Cygwin. Everything seams to work fine but the rails console. When I want to run the console, this is the error I get:

```
$ rails console
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/unit (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:225:in `initialize_console'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:153:in `load_console'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:26:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It appears you don't have the `minitest/unit` gem installed, but that gem isn't required to run a default rails app. Can you post the contents of your `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the gem "minitest" installed in your Gemfile.

Comment: As simple as that, but you helped me a lot ;)
Thanks, it works

Comment: This worked for me too! I reported the problem here. Please vote for them to fix it: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9256